# PostgreSQL Master Script To Run Several Separate Scripts

Tags: php, postgresql, pgadmin

pgAdmin version 1.22.1, PostgreSQL.

I have 9 different SQL scripts that I would like to be able to execute all at once with a "Master Script". I want to be able to keep these files separate for easier editing of them though, so this "Master Script" must just call/run the nine separate scripts. I came up (Through some research) with the following:

```
-- Master script.

\i 01_name1.sql
\i 02_name2.sql
\i 03_name3.sql
\i 04_name4.sql
\i 05_name5.sql
\i 06_name6.sql
\i 07_name7.sql
\i 08_name9.sql
\i 09_name10.sql

-- EOF
```

However this gives the error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 3: \i 01_name1.sql
        ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 22
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem is before the "\i" [most probably a BOM]

Comment: @wildplasser how do I go about fixing that?

Comment: First: detect *if* there is a BOM. second: if there is one: remove it using a sane editor, or tr, or dd, or a tiny script or program.